# I keep getting a error when I execute the send Credentials void

Tags: android

When I run my code i get a error when the `SendCredentials` void is executed.

The **error** is:-

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.messager, PID: 16131
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6614)
     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6591)
     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:786)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25948)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6614) 
     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6591) 
     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:786) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25948) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.DataInputStream.readLine()'
     on a null object reference
     at com.example.messager.MainActivity.SendCredentials(MainActivity.java:69)
     at com.example.messager.MainActivity.SendMessage(MainActivity.java:26)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6614) 
     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6591) 
     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:786) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25948) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

**My Code is**

```
package com.example.messager;

import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText stopPort;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void SendMessage(View view)throws IOException{
        EditText emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
        String Username = emailText.getText().toString();
        EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        String Password = passwordText.getText().toString();

        System.out.println("Your username is " + Username + "Your Password is " + Password);
        SendCredentials();
    }
    public void SendCredentials()throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Work");
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.114", 4321);
        System.out.println("Work");
        DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        dOut.writeByte(1);
        dOut.writeUTF("This is a test");
        dOut.flush();
        System.out.println("Work");
    }
    public void Check(){



    }
}
```

`

Comment: Where is your line 69? You missed many things.

Comment: I believe many of your work have been removed from this question, after the third `println("Work")`. Please add them all. Besides, it is better to use `android.util.Log` instead of `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to above code and exception trace 2 things can be wrong.

1. check your code for 
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.DataInputStream.readLine()' on a null object reference at
2. In xml layout file, have you declared "check" method on android:onClick
   i.e. android:onClick="check", if yes then your check method should look like this

public void Check(View view){
}

Can you share you xml layout file as well.

Comment: Neither of these helped but i put my xml code in the post above

Comment: I have rewrite your code now its works fine. Please create socket connection separate thread, i.e. another then main thread.    Please see my another answer as below....

Answer (score 0):

yea my xml code is '

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Welcome"
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/passwordWrapper"
        android:layout_width="387dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="444dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/emailWrapper"
        android:layout_width="397dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="368dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text=""/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:onClick="SendMessage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

'

Answer (score -1):

```
public void SendMessage(View view) throws IOException {
    EditText emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
    String Username = emailText.getText().toString();
    EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    String Password = passwordText.getText().toString();

    System.out.println("Your username is " + Username + "Your Password is " + Password);
    SendCredentials();
}

public void SendCredentials() throws IOException {
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}

public void Check() {
}


private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Activity activity;
    IOException ioException;

    MyAsyncTask() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            System.out.println("Work");
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.114", 4321);
            System.out.println("Work");
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            dOut.writeByte(1);
            dOut.writeUTF("This is a test");
            dOut.flush();
            System.out.println("Work");

            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.ioException = e;

        }
```

}
 }

Comment: See the last "Caused by" of the stacktrace, the call to `readLine()` for a `DataInputStream` inside `SendCredentials` lies in line 69 of `MainActivity.java` immediately generate NPE, but that call was missing in the code provided by OP, then OP must be missing the core code, which using other method won't reproduce or solve the issue.

Comment: Don't aggress with downvoted. :et add the completed code, please run this project, I am able to run application with abobe code with any NPE.

Comment: The hint of downvote is "This answer is not useful.", and it suits. The logcat and the code given by OP shows the code isn't complete, so writing any non-NPE code won't solve that question at all (so this is "not useful").